Login to mariadb via .cgi script denial
New forum user here so let me know if I do anything off protocol or use improper terms.
I'm migrating some perl scripts from a CentOS7 machine to Alma9 and of course mysql/mariadb is a more recent version (10.5.22) and uses the new non-password type credentials logins. I confess that I probably don't fully understand this new login system. The login in the scripts is via a  DBI->connect type line for DB login. Many of the .pl scripts are called from
/var/spool/cron/root

so of course they run since root is starting them even though the original script logins reference root@localhost and give a password. Since it is root running the script it just ignores the PW bit.
However I also have .cgi scripts that use the same sort of DBI->connect type line for DB login. These script are getting run from a web page on localhost that runs the script and now it isn't root running the script and the login fails. In /var/log/httpd/error_log I see lines like
[cgid:error] [pid 33953:tid 34123] [client 192.168.1.10:62362] DBI connect('xantrex:localhost','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at /usr/local/solar-web_monitor/cgi-bin/power_graph.cgi line 26.: /usr/local/solar-web_monitor/cgi-bin/power_graph.cgi

Line 26 mentioned is the DBI->connect line with the creds. Does anyone know the proper way to configure mysql/mariadb to be able to pass login credentials via a .cgi script? I saw some references to mods to my.cnf to do
skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address
but a quick try of those did not make a difference and mariadb didn't like those options at all.
Please advise,
Alan D.
OK, as per Bill's comment I clearly need to add in more detail.
Yes, I'm using mariadb, not mysql.
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@version ;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.5.22-MariaDB |
+-----------------+

However mysql commands in perl scripts go through to mariadb just as they did in COS7. History is that COS5 used straight mysql, COS7 switched to mysql commands but mariadb behind the scenes as a drop in replacement. Now I've installed Alam9 and it came with "mysql" and something called "sqlite" already installed
dnf list installed |grep sql
mysql-selinux.noarch                             1.0.10-1.el9                       @appstream
sqlite-libs.x86_64                               3.34.1-7.el9_3                     @anaconda 

I did and install of mariadb to keep consistent with what I already had in COS7 and because sqlite looked like I'd have to modify all my code to use it.
So back to the original question: How can I make a public user accessing my web page that calls the .cgi script be able to access the data in the mariadb dtabase w/o getting a login rejection? I'm still puzzled. Further, if I use systemctl to stop mysql and sqlite is that going to also damage mariadb, the linux system seems to somehow be equating the two?
As per Dan's request and suggestions:
    > mariadb-upgrade
This installation of MariaDB is already upgraded to 10.5.22-MariaDB.
There is no need to run mysql_upgrade again for 10.5.22-MariaDB.
You can use --force if you still want to run mysql_upgrade

MariaDB [(none)]> show create user root@localhost ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER for root@localhost                                                                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '*BE4F2B53E0AFFD846F159BA58C6C2DB3EC2CF3E5' OR unix_socket |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for root@localhost ;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '*BE4F2B53E0AFFD846F159BA58C6C2DB3EC2CF3E5' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

The suggestions about the root password I wonder about. The issue is not that root can run mariadb but that the apache running the .cgi script doesn't have root privilages so the authentication is seen as an non-local attempt to log in and is rejected. Am I seeing this correctly. Also look at
93 dunwellguitar3:/etc/httpd/conf 
> mariadb -u root@localhost
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost'
594 dunwellguitar3:/etc/httpd/conf 
> sudo mariadb -u root@localhost
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost'
595 dunwellguitar3:/etc/httpd/conf 
> mariadb -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 179
Server version: 10.5.22-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Only bare bones root is allowed to log in.
ANSWER
OK, I re-read the authentication page more carefully that Dan referenced more carefully than I had in the past. It mentions two ways to revert to the old authentication:
 The option can also be set in an option file in an option group supported by mariadb-install-db. For example:

[mysql_install_db]
auth_root_authentication_method=normal

If the option is set in an option file and if mariadb-install-db is executed, then mariadb-install-db 
will read this option from the option file, and it will automatically set this option.
The default MariaDB option file is called /etc/my.cnf 

I had done this and it failed to  make any difference. (Also just FYI you don't run "mariadb-install-db" any more but instead use mariadb-upgrade.)
The second method that Dan also  mentions is to do the ALTER USER mode from within mariadb
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("verysecret")

This did work!! So now Apache runs the script but mariadb allows the old authentication method and takes the root@localhost and a password and my .cgi scripts now run successfully.
MANY THANKS, DAN, for pointing that out.
This doesn't actually answer the original question. If you don't revert to the old authentication then the question remails of how to force a .cgi script run by apache to get maridb to either allow root login or to pretend to run as root so maridb will authenticate from unix_socket.
I actually don't care since I'm up and running but the question remains as a "exercise for the student". I'd still be interested in any conversation on that.

Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? These are two different database products, and they are not compatible. You mention version 10.5.22, which is MariaDB. But you tagged the question [tag:mysql] and you reference "mysql/mariadb" as though they are interchangeable, which they are not.

I have mariadb installed but if I say mariadb -u root aor mysql -u root both commands go to the same place. So in truth I don't know which is the actual database behind my perl/mysql commands. Is there a way to find out difinitively?

Did you run mariadb-upgrade? That you have an error message indicates that the error is on the MariaDB side. With a valid login look at SHOW CREATE USER root@localhost and SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost. Check the password in the perl scripts isn't being affected by perl escape/formatting. Try resetting with ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket OR mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('thisisthepassword')

mariadb -u root@localhost - note the use is just root - so mariadb -u root. Localhost is append within the server as that's where the connection comes from.
